# How to load images serially with Glide in an activity?

Tags: java, android, android-glide

Total Android noobie here. How do I load images serially into same ImageView (e.g. next image after the previous image is loaded like a slide show) with Glide? Only way I could think of doing this would be to make some kind of AsyncTask to monitor when Glide's onResourceReady is executed. There must be an easier way or is there? first I tried to make a simple waiting loop with ImageReady boolean to see when resource is ready (updated in onResourceReady) but the boolean never gets updated (must be a thread thing)?

```
private void updateCustomImageView(final LinkedList<String> imageUrls, final ImageView imageView){

    for (String url:imageUrls) {
        imageReady = false;
        Glide
                .with(this)
                .load(url)
                .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        imageReady = true;
                        Log.d("notready", "notready ");
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        imageReady = true;
                        Log.d("ready", "ready ");
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .into(imageView);

         while(!imageReady);
     }


}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include the code you mention you tried, even if it doesn't work. It gives answerers a place to start from.

Comment: See: http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/transitions.html#cross-fading-across-requests. A ViewSwitcher containing two ImageViews often works well for this kind of thing.

Comment: I already deleted the code, but I added an example to my question. Thanks for quick answer.